# Как убрать неопределенность при множественном наследовании?

Tags: c++, множественное-наследование

Есть базовый класс First содержащий 1 абсолютно виртуальную функцию

> virtual QString getInfo() =0;

2 Производных класса Basic, Vip, причем

> class Basic : virtual public First
>
> class Vip : public Basic, public OtherClass (совершенно другой класс,
>   не относится к этой иерархии)

И есть класс SuperVip, который и является причиной проблемы

> class SuperVip : public Vip, public Basic

когда я пытаюсь сделать следующее

```
SuperVip* svip = dynamic_cast<SuperVip*>(tmpBasic)  //некий указатель на Basic
QString result = svip->Basic::getInfo();
```

Получаю

> Basic is an ambiguous base of SuperVip

Указывающий на строку с result

Я понимаю, что это из-за того, что SuperVip наследует Basic и Vip в свою очередь тоже наследует Basic, вот и получается неопределенность.

Мне нужно убрать ее **не применяя** виртуальное наследование.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как явно указать компилятору, какой метод использовать и избежать неопределенности?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A
{
public:
    virtual void func(void) = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void func(void) override {cout << "B" << endl;}
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    void func(void) override {cout << "C" << endl;}
};

class D : public C, public B
{
public:
    void func(void) override {cout << "D" << endl;}
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.func();                //D
    d.C::func();             //C
    //Преобразуем ccылку к ссылку на класс одной из ветвей наследования
    static_cast<C &>(d).B::func(); //B
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло